# Extract line before first empty line after match

Tags: regex, bash, terminal, text-processing

I have some CSV file in this form:

```
* COMMENT
* COMMENT
100 ; 1706 ; 0.18 ; 0.45 ; 0.00015 ; 0.1485 ; 0.03 ; 1 ; 1 ; 2 ; 280 ; 100 ; 100 ; 

* COMMENT
* COMMENT

* ZT vector
0; 367; p; nan
1; 422; p; nan
2; 1; d; nan

* KS vector
0; 367; p; 236.27
1; 422; p; 236.27
2; 1; d; 236.27



*Total time: 4.04211
```

I need to extract the last line before an empty line after matching the pattern `KS vector`.

To be clearer, in the above example I would like to extract the line

```
2; 1; d; 236.27
```

since it's the non empty line just before the first empty one after I got the match with `KS vector`.

I would also like to use the same script to extract the same kind of line after matching the pattern `ZT vector`, that in the above example would return

```
2; 1; d; nan
```

I need to do this because I need the first number of that line, since it tells me the number of consecutive non-empty lines after `KS vector`.
My current workaround is this:

```
# counting number of lines after matching "KS vector" until first empty line
var=$(sed -n '/KS vector/,/^$/p' file | wc -l)
# Subtracting 2 to obtain actual number of lines
var=$(($var-2))
```

But if I could extract directly the last line I could extract the first element (`2` in the example) and add 1 to it to obtain the same number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ***awk*** expression:

```
awk -v vec="KS vector" '$0~vec{ f=1 }f && !NF{ print r; exit }f{ r=$0 }' file
```

- `vec` - variable containing the needed pattern/vector
- `$0~vec{ f=1 }` - on encountering the needed pattern/vector - set the flag `f` in active state
- `f{ r=$0 }` - while the flag `f` is active(under needed vector section) - capture the current line into variale `r`
- `f && !NF{ print r; exit }` - (`NF` - total number of fields, if the line is empty - there's no fields `!NF`) on encountering empty line while iterating through the needed vector lines - print the last captured non-empty line `r`
- `exit` - exit script execution immediately (avoiding redundant actions/iterations)

The output:

```
2; 1; d; 236.27
```

---

If you want to just print the actual number of lines under found vector use the following:

```
awk -v vec="KS vector" '$0~vec{ f=1 }f && !NF{ print r+1; exit }f{ r=$1 }' file
3
```

Comment: Could you explain how your script works? I'm not familiar with awk. I understand that when "KS vector" is found you set a flag equal to 1 and then you print "r" (?) when "f==1 && !NF" (I understand that "!NF" means that the line is empty, right?), but then I get lost

Comment: @jackscorrow, see my explanation

Comment: Thank you! One last question, if I may. I tried to switch the order of the logical `if`s (expecting the output to be the same) in this way: `awk '$0~"KS vector"{ f=1 } f{ r=$1 } f && !NF{ print r+1; exit }' file` but the output now is `1` instead of `3`. Do you know why?
I thought to change the order just for a better readability on my side, it's not a problem to keep the code as you wrote it, but I didn't expect the output to change

Comment: of course, this 2 statements `f{ r=$1 } f && !NF{ print r+1; exit }` will be checked sequentially (like clockwise). So, on encountering empty line this `f{ r=$1 }` will record the empty value `$1` to `r`, then, `f && !NF{ print r+1; exit }` will just evaluate `0+1` - giving you `1` as a result. So, the order of statements is important

Answer (score 3):

You're going about this the wrong way. All you need is to put awk into paragraph mode and print 1 less than the number of lines in the record (since you don't want to include the KS vector line in your count):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/KS vector/{print NF-1}' file
3
```

Here's how awk sees the record when you put it into paragraph mode (by setting RS to null) with newline-separated fields (by setting FS to a newline):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/KS vector/{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NF, i, "<"$i">"}' file
4 1 <* KS vector>
4 2 <0; 367; p; 236.27>
4 3 <1; 422; p; 236.27>
4 4 <2; 1; d; 236.27>
```

Comment: I don't know. Your answer is more compact for sure, but what kind of advantages would it have in respect to the other?

Comment: The other being the currently accepted one? I'd have thought it being simpler would be enough but in addition to that this is easier to modify, less fragile (can be trivially tweaked to only test the first line in a block with `$1~/.../` if KS vector appears multiple times in a block and it doesn't rely on the 1st value of the last line), and easier to build on later (e.g. to print the 2nd line after KS vector is just `print $2`). That's all kinda theoretical though - for the data you have it probably doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk '$0 ~ "KS vector" { valid=1;getline } valid==1 { cnt++;dat[cnt]=$0 } $0=="" { valid="" } END { print dat[cnt-1]  }' filename
```

Check for any lines matching "KS vector". Set a valid flag and then read in the next line. Read the data into an array with an incremented counter. When space is encountered, reset the valid flag. At the end print the last but one element of the dat array.